# How do I automatically show the desktop every 30 mins on linux mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Are there any ways to do it? How do I automate Win+D to be pressed every 30 mins without me pressing the combination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xdotool` allows to send keystrokes.

To install:

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

In your case this should work:

```
xdotool key super+d
```

For every 30 mins

```
while sleep 1800; do xdotool key super+d; done
```

or

```
watch -n1800  xdotool key super+d
```